# Is using System.Data.DataTable in Powershell bad pratice?

Tags: powershell

A friend told me to avoid using it as it is deprecated. However, I can't seem to find anything about that. Is there a better way to to read data from a database with System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection then loading the reader into System.Data.DataTable.

Comment: I see no deprecation notice in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx), googling it also didn't reveal any, so I'd say pay no heed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so, you can’t really avoid using .net objects, considering that’s what all commands emit, one way or another : P

[9:36]
you can usually check MSDN to see if a class is deprecated

[9:39]
e.g. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable  - which doesn’t mention it’s deprecated, so you should be good to go!

[9:40]
Generally, you might consider balancing readability (many folks find PowerShell commands easier to understand than working directly with .net objects), with the performance and functionality you might gain by using .net objects directly

[9:42]
Abstraction is also good - generally, in a script other folks might use, you would want to abstract out those .NET calls even if you use them, and ideally, re-use an existing tool…   so, for example, I might prefer to use Invoke-SqlCmd2 (https://github.com/sqlcollaborative/dbatools/blob/master/functions/Invoke-SqlCmd2.ps1) , rather than 10 lines of .NET-ish code directly in a script (basically… https://powershell.org/2015/08/16/abstraction-and-configuration-data/)